# Is passing a huge amount of data to a function memory intensive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, performance, benchmarking, sidekiq

We're currently exposing an API endpoint to receive massive amounts of JSON data (1000+).

My current implmentation is this:

- Send raw data to a worker by means of passing the raw data as a function parameter
- Then let the background worker(sidekiq) do all the parsing, processing etc. etc.

However, my senior dev is saying that passing raw values is memory intensive. Instead, he is suggesting the ff. implementation:

- Save raw data to redis
- Fetch redis key in background worker
- Then have sidekiq do processing (JSON.parse, etc. etc.)

But for me, this is just additional overhead and a case of premature optimization.

I already did a benchmark in passing a huge data to a function.

Code is just a simple passing of data to a function:

`RandomClass.new(raw_data)`

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
18920 json objects    40.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                      1.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                      0.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
3784  json objects    40.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                      1.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                      0.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
   1  json objects    40.000  memsize (     0.000  retained)
                      1.000  objects (     0.000  retained)
                      0.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
```

This is using [benchmark-memory](https://github.com/michaelherold/benchmark-memory)

To be honest, I'm much more concerned about the memory allocation in parsing the JSON data rather than memory allocated by passing a value to the background worker.

So, is there any validity to the claim of passing huge data to a function as memory intensive?

Comment: If the data is in memory it's irrelevant: all you pass is a reference to what's already in memory. There's more overhead in shuffling the data to/from Redis. That said, it may still make sense to do so, but it's impossible to know from the information provided.

Comment: @DaveNewton Forgive my ignorance when is the data considered to be in memory? The data comes from a request from an external service. Does that help?

Comment: It's in memory if it's in memory. If  you *can* pass the data to a function then it's in memory, otherwise how else would you be passing it?

Comment: @DaveNewton By that definition, then it's in memory.

Comment: Well yeah. You can't pass a reference to something that doesn't exist. (Well, you can, but it's probably not what you intended.) Also, when you save it to Redis, you're passing a reference to the data to either something that gives it to Redis, or directly to the Redis driver. It's the same data, it doesn't matter what you're passing it to. That isn't the real question, though; the memory usage will be the same as far as has been discussed: the data is in memory no matter what. The issue(s) arise with how it's being processed, by what thread(s), etc.

Comment: quick answer .. yes .. huge amount of data takes huge chunk of memory .. and when you declare more variables and assignments inside the method to process them means more memory as well.

Comment: Write it in the simplest manner possible.  Worry about performance if it doesn't meant your load requirements.